# how to apply nsmallest on groupby function

Tags: python

I have a data frame which contains three columns - `ID, Name, Type`.

I have sorted the data frame using ID and Type using the following code
    `df_MI2 = df_MI1.sort_values(by=['ID', 'TYPE'])`

So, now I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
+--------+--------+-------+
|ID      |Name    |Type   |
|12      |A       |1      |
|12      |A       |2      |
|12      |A       |3      |
|12      |A       |4      |
|13      |B       |2      |
|13      |B       |4      |
|14      |C       |4      |
|15      |D       |3      |
|15      |D       |4      |
|15      |D       |5      |
|16      |D       |6      |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Now, I want to select only the first two values of Type for each ID. How can I do that?

I have tried the following:

1. `df_MI3 = df_MI2.groupby('ID').nsmallest(2, 'TYPE')`

This gives me an error.

2.
    `df_MI3 = df_MI2.groupby('ID').min()`
This is giving me only one `"TYPE"` for each `"ID"`

Comment: Thank You, Rakesh. Can you help me figure out how to get the table in the grey colored box like you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution very simply by using

```
df_MI3 = df_MI2.groupby('ID').head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cumsum`, `cumcount` and create a new column as `increment`.

Then drop all rows where `increment > 2`.

Please find the sample below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'ID' : ['I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I2', 'I3', 'I3', 'I4', 'I5', 'I5', 'I5', 'I6'],
        'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
        'Type': [1,2,3,4,2,4,4,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
m=df['ID']
b = m.cumsum()
df['increment'] = np.where(m, df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()+1, 0)
df = df[df['increment'] < 3]
df.drop('increment', 1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output is

```
    ID Name  Type
0   I2    A     1
1   I2    A     2
4   I3    B     2
5   I3    B     4
6   I4    C     4
7   I5    D     3
8   I5    D     4
10  I6    D     6
[Finished in 1.2s]
```